# pytest capsys with custom exception

Tags: python, pytest

I am having trouble testing the output of a custom exception in pytest.

```py
import pytest


class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, extra_message: str):
        self.message = extra_message
        super().__init__(self.message)
        # Should not need to print this as Exception already does this 
        # print(self.message)


def test_should_get_capsys_output(capsys):
    with pytest.raises(CustomException):
        raise CustomException("This should be here.")

    out, err = capsys.readouterr()
    
    # This should not be true 
    assert out == ''
    assert err == ''
    assert 'This' not in out
```

This example should not pass as I should be able to assert something came out in the output. If I `print(self.message)` I end up getting the message printed twice when actually used but only then does capsys collect stdout.

I've also tried with variations of caplog and capfd to no avail. [This SO solution] recommends adding an output to the `with pytest.raises(...) as info` and testing the `info` but I would have expected capsys to work as well.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sort of confused by what you're asking?

A python exception will stop execution of the current test, even within pytest. So by raising the exception inside a context manager (`with` statement) we're simulating/catching it ***before*** it gets a chance to stop our current test and go to `stderr`.

Comment: Right so pytest is catching the rest of the exception which is why the message is never put in stdout or stderr.  Thanks!